# Dockerized Nginx and Django, how to serve static files

Tags: django, nginx, docker

Im using Docker to containerize my Django environment, which looks like this (simplified a bit):

1. A Nginx (official image) docker container
2. An Ubuntu docker container with uwsgi and Django

The Nginx container are serving the uwsgi just fine, but I have not found a way to serve static files.

```
upstream proceed {
    server proceed:8000;
}

 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /static {
        alias /srv/www/proceed/static/; # What to do here? 
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass proceed;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

**Question:** Whats the best way to serve static files from another container? A solution not involving volumes are preferable.

Comment: You need to make your files available inside the container.  That means either (a) mounting them as a volume or (b) baking them into a new image.  Take your pick.

Comment: @larsks -- What would be the best way to bake them into the new image? That's ideally what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said [@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) you need  [share volumes between containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volumes-from-container-volumes-from).

Your django `Dockerfile` need to contains volume definitions

```
FROM ubuntu 
....
VOLUME  /srv/www/proceed/static # there is path to your static
```

When you run nginx container you need add `volumes-from` argument

```
docker run nginx --volumes-from django
```

And than you nginx config will works fine.

**Note!** path to static content into django container and into nginx container must be the same!